# Redirect is not working in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, url, redirect, struts2

Here is my index.jsp file:

```xml
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>HOME</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <s:action name="getUrl"></s:action>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my struts.xml:

```xml
<struts>
  <action name="getUrl" class="UrlAction">
    <result name="redirect" type="redirect">${url}</result>
  </action>
</struts>
```

Here is my action class:

```
public class UrlAction extends ActionSupport {

  private String url;

  public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  public String getUrl(){
    return url;
  }

  public String execute() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Entering execute() of Action");
    url = "https://www.google.com/";
    return "redirect";
  }

}
```

So when I run index.jsp then it should redirect me to https://www.google.com, but I am not getting that. It is printing "Entering execute() of Action". It means it is going in Action class. Please correct me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Why is UrlAction in the default package? As defined in the Struts2 XML action mapping.

Comment: Will it make difference?

Comment: Not if it really is in the default namespace... but if it is in a named package then it wouldn't. It's pretty rare for developers not to put their classes in a package. You'll typically create a lot of them, organizing them is a good idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should change

```xml
<result name="redirect" type="redirect">${url}</result>
```

to

```xml
<result name="redirect" type="redirect">
    <param name="location">${url}</param>
</result>
```

and

```xml
<s:action name="getUrl"></s:action>
```

to

```xml
<s:action name="getUrl" executeResults="true"></s:action>
```

to make it works;

but, even after doing that, you won't have your page redirected, because that is *not* what the `<s:action>` tag does, [according to the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/action.html):

> This tag enables developers to call actions directly from a JSP page by specifying the action name and an optional namespace. The body content of the tag is used to render the results from the Action. Any result processor defined for this action in struts.xml will be ignored, unless the executeResult parameter is specified.

You can find an example of usage here: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-action-tag-example/

<s>I guess you will probably see the redirected google page inside your tag (after the modifies)</s>

---

EDIT

You should describe accurately what you are trying to achieve; you started by asking a question about the `<s:action>` tag, but I'm pretty sure that is not what you need (although I've still not understood precisely what you want, apart from a "redirect" somewhere at some point)

If you want to redirect immediately when opening the page, just use `<s:url>` tag to mount an url to your action, and put it in a javascript script altering the location:

```xml
<script>
    location.href = "<s:url action="getUrl.action" />";
</script>
```

(but it would be weird, because if you need to redirect when coming from another action, there isn't a reason to pass from the JSP page, just use `redirectAction` result instead of `redirect` result  )

If you instead want to redirect when pressing a button, use `<s:submit>` tag:

```xml
<s:submit action="getUrl.action" value="press here to redirect" />
```

First identify and describe *agnostically* your *goal* , then acquire information about the technologies that help you to do that.

Comment: +1, oh, right. But even with the change, the response has already been written to, and using `executeResult` still shouldn't redirect, no?

Comment: Yeah, probably; I've really never used that tag... I'd be curious to know it, but not enough to test :))

Comment: I tried as you said.Still it is not redirecting.But I found an interesting thing that if I directly paste "getUrl.action" in browser then it is redirecting, but not when I running index.jsp

Comment: @pranaygodha Could you wait a little bit until document is loaded then call the action.

Comment: @AndreaLigios `<s:url>` tag worked for me. Thank you. My goal was to hit index.jsp which will call action class and from action class I can generate any URl, where I want to be redirected. So I used `redirect` in my action class.